# drupal7 split scripts variable for header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, drupal-7

I have a problem with my responsible design in Internet explorer 7. 
When you load the page, the page will be shown first in the mobile version, and afterwards it jumps to the correct layout.

I think I found the reason, but an solution still stays away. 
So my javascript files are being inserted at the bottom of my page. (Drupal + combined)

like this:

```
<?php echo $scripts ?>
```

So the reason why internet explorer 7 has the jump from mobile to desktop is because the javascript files are being loaded at the bottom.

So my solution was to add the $scripts variable to the head of the page. Here we didn't have that problem anymore, but the next problems came up:

- site loaded slower
- some javascript didn't work anymore when going further into the website.

So I had another solution, but I have no Idea how to implement this. Could someone help me with this?

I would like to have the $scripts variable split in for example $scripts_header and $scripts_footer. (that is a string with the combined js files).

The only scripts files in the $script_header would be the jquery files. All the others can be in de $scripts_footer.

The jquery files are loaded with cdn. (jquery_update module) if this module is deactivated, drupal uses the included jquery library from drupal.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9  & (!IEMobile)]><script src="/js/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

So is there a way to split those files. (maybe in the template.php file?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/pascalduez/1418121
This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, It didn't solve the problem with mobile, I placed the script tag in the header. I know it's not the "correct" way for loading script files, but now the problem has been resolved. our answer was also interesting for other cases.